# jquery regex get several key not only one

Tags: regex

I would like to get

```
PA-1400-11PA ADP-40PH ABA
```

Here html code

```
    </div>
<div class="ref">
    <h2 id='affiche_sous_titre'>eee :</h2>              <p>
                <a href='eee' title='PA-1400-11PA' class='lien_menu'>PA-1400-11PA</a>  -  <a href='uuu' title='ADP-40PH ABA' class='lien_menu'>ADP-40PH ABA</a>             </p>
                </div>
<div class="modele_tout">
    </div>
<div class="star-customer">
```

Here my reg code

```
line=line.replace(/[\"\']lien_menu[\"\']>(.*?)<\/a>/ig,"$1\n")
```

But I have only

```
ADP-40PH ABA
```

What is the problem.I dont understand?
thanks for your help

Comment: You shouldn't be using regexes for this anyway. You're relying on the fact that the `class` attribute appears last and doesn't contain any other classes. This won't work if other developers / libraries change the HTML. I'd do it (in jQuery) using `var links = $('#affiche_sous_titre a')`, then call `.text()` on each element of `links`. Better yet, I'd add a `data` attribute and call `.data(...)` instead.

Comment: How exactly are you getting `ADP-40PH ABA` as output?

Comment: thanks david ,i would like to get PA-1400-11PA ADP-40PH ABA as ouput